# jQuery: how to compare multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, input

How can you compare multiple input in the same form if they ALL have the same value? I need to check if they all have the same value or not.

```
<input type="text" class="inputclass"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass"/>
<input type="text" class="inputclass"/>
....
```

Comment: You want to know if they ***all*** have the same value ? or if ***any*** of them have the same value ?

Comment: It must check all input if they all have the same value or not.

Comment: Input class is an awfully redundant name for the class of an input (very redundant, because it's too redundant.). You probably should avoid naming each one, why could these not simply be inputs with type text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = $("input.inputclass").map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();

var allHaveSameValue = $.unique(arr).length == 1;
```

Here is the jsfiddle.net
http://jsfiddle.net/epignosisx/jzWUA/4/

UPDATE======

As @Anurag pointed out, $.unique is only for DOM elements. Here is a different implementation:

```
function uniqueArray(arr){
    return $.grep(arr,function(v,k){
        return $.inArray(v,arr) === k;
    });
}

var arr = $(".inputclass").map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
var allHaveSameValue = uniqueArray(arr).length == 1;
```

Basically uses a function that will truly return a unique array.

Comment: @Esailija - This solution is fundamentally sound, but does not work in its current state. The problem is with uniquing the array or removing duplicates. jQuery's unique method only accepts an array of DOM nodes, and does not work for other types of objects. Also, **assuming** unique worked for all types of arrays, you'd need to call `.length` to get the number of unique elements in the array before doing the comparison with `1`.

Comment: Ok testing `.length` makes sense, I thought you had some magic voodoo with `==` comparing numbers and arrays :P (the original was `$.unique(arr) == 1`) It still does far too much work though.. you only need to loop through the collection once with `.every`

Comment: Interesting. It's true that $.unique is supposed to work only with DOM elements. However, seems to work based on the jsfiddle I posted.

Comment: This works, so its basically storing all the values in an array and checking the array....pretty easy with a couple of lines of code. Thanks!

Comment: @epignosisx - Don't rely on it working based on one example. Try `$.unique(["1", "2", "1"])` for example. It returns the array `["1", "2", "1"]`.

Comment: @Anurag please look at the updated answer. I dropped the $.unique call for a custom unique array implementation.

Comment: And how do you prevent that all of the values are empty(as nothing is the same as nothing).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/EpYTh/

```
var firstInput = $(".inputclass").eq(0).val();
 var equalField = true;
$(".inputclass").each(function(){

    if($(this).val() != firstInput){
        equalField = false;
    }   
});


alert(equalField);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasSameValue() {
  var sameValue = true, formVal = $('.inputclass').first().val();
  $('.inputclass').each(function(){
    sameValue = sameValue && (formVal === $(this).val());
    if (!sameValue) { return false; }
  });
  return sameValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allHaveSameValue = $(".inputclass").toArray().every( function( input, index, inputs ){
return input.value === inputs[0].value;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

http://jsfiddle.net/zTSag/1/